# Loop, hide columns and r formattable

Tags: r, formattable

I have this

```
A<-1:10
B<-10:1
C<-11:20
df<-data.frame(id=1:10,A,B,C,tA=A>5,tB=B>5)
```

I'm using formattable and this is what I would like to have (Output 1)

```
formattable(df, list(
            id = formatter("span",
                   style = ~ style(color = "gray")),
            A=formatter("span",
                          style =  ~ style(color = ifelse(tA==TRUE, "green", "red")),
                          ~ icontext(ifelse(tA==TRUE, "arrow-up", "arrow-down"), A)),
            B=formatter("span",
                        style =  ~ style(color = ifelse(tB==TRUE, "green", "red")),
                        ~ icontext(ifelse(tB==TRUE, "arrow-up", "arrow-down"), B)),
            C=color_tile("transparent", "lightpink"),
            tA=FALSE,
            tB=FALSE))
```

The problem is I would like to loop for columns A and B.

```
formattable(df, 
        lapply(df[,c("A","B")], function(col)
        {
          col=formatter("span",
                        style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x>XXX, "green", "red")),
                        x ~ icontext(ifelse(x>val[1], "arrow-up", "arrow-down"), x))
        }
        ))
```

The question: How to combine lapply and formattable to have like in Output 1?

Many thanks.